# Handlebars: html prints in console but does not render

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I am building an app on express and handlebars. I am trying to allow the user to input a search term, which then triggers the following:

1. The search term gets passed to a route on my server
2. That route makes a call to an external API via axios
3. The data comes back, and handlebars renders it onto a "search results" page.

Handlebars is taking in the data and making a perfect html document that then, for some reason, doesn't get rendered in the browswer window. However, if I open the browser's dev tools, go to "network", click on the request, and then "preview," I see the page that I would like rendered. I suspect I'm pointing the handlebars `res.render` in the wrong direction but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I have `search.js` file linked up to an html page that gives the user a search bar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchButton").on("click", function() {
    const query = $("#recipeSearch")
      .val()
      .trim();
    const search = { searchTerm: query };

    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/search",
      method: "POST",
      data: search
    }).then(result => console.log(result));
  });
});
```

Then in my routes, I have a post route defined like so:

```
app.post("/api/search", function(req, res) {
    let searchTerm = req.body.searchTerm;
    let apiKey = process.env.SPOON_APIKEY;
    let queryUrl = `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/search?query=${searchTerm}&apiKey=${apiKey}`;

    axios.get(queryUrl).then((results) => {
      // then render the retrieved data to a handlebars page
      res.render("search-results", { recipes: results.data.results });
    });
  });
```

handlebars files:

```
views/
  search-results.handlebars
  layouts/
    main.handlebars
```

search-results contains the following:

```
<ul>
  {{#each recipes }}
  <li>{{this.title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The result, in the browser dev tools, looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFAdc.png

What am I missing? Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere?  I ask as it is quite clear why your code logs to the console.  That is the only thing you do with your data.  I don't see any handlebars-related code, either.

Comment: not copied, no. But based on simpler handlebars apps that I've built from tutorials.

Comment: Show the rest of your code.

Comment: What in particular do you need to see? This is for a collaborative project and I'm not comfortable sharing everything as I didn't write everything myself

Comment: This question is tagged with handlebars, so how about the part that you expect to take the result of the search and interpolate it into the html?

Comment: see edits above

Comment: I see that I was not clear.  I will try once more: You perform an ajax request.  You expect the result of that request to be interpolated into the html, but none of that code is present in any of the above snippets.  Every tutorial I've seen on handlebars suggests you do this with `let a = Handlebars.compile(str);a(obj);`, or some variation thereof, but I do not see this snippet in any of your code.

Comment: see the edit to the ```routes``` above

Comment: Your server has no direct control over the already-rendered state of the client.  Not unless you add some code to the client to interpret the server response and respond accordingly.  While this may not be true for WASM, it is here.  So you made your ajax request; the server has already rendered the page.  You need to either implement an MVC structure on your frontend to handle the data in a clean way, or you just need to directly inject your server-rendered html from the ajax request.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, the last example can be accomplished with a simple: `.then(result => $("#target-container").html(result));`  For better data handling, I'd recommend looking into VueJS, React, or Angular/AngularJS.  These are advanced frameworks, for the record, but they tend to handle data in a cleaner way than just overwriting html directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and in conclusion I believe (I could be wrong) the way to work around this and still achieve this is to send your data to your front end by using `res.send()` instead of `res.render()`, register a partial from the front end and then render the data on the front end. I will let you know how this works out...